# How to use remote IPv6 over ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh, ipv6, vps

I have a cheap VPS with 1 IPv4 and 5 IPv6.

I want to use 1 of the unused IPv6 connections on my computer so I can start using IPv6

Does anyone have any ideas? I would prefer an all OpenSSH based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with the hassle. There are several IPv6 tunnel providers that will give you multiple IPv6 *subnets* for free. My personal fave is [Hurricane Electric](http://tunnelbroker.net/).